# How to solve NoClassDefFoundError when trying to call a testng.xml file from Actionperformed/jbutton in separate class?

Tags: java, xml, maven, testng, classpath

I am trying to run parallel tests using Selenium WebDriver and testNG from a Java GUI testbed that I created.  The testbed is in a separate class from the testNG environment.  When I run the parallel tests from the XML file, the tests run fine.  When I launch the GUI and try to click the button I have assigned to call the XML file, I get "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/testng/TestNG".  Based on answers I have researched, it seems that this is a class path issue.  I have made sure that all the necessary testNG jar files are in the build path.

```
else if(e.getSource() == bTestParallel) { //Test Parallel
      try {

            TestAllTestCases.runXML();

        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

That is the code in actionperformed for the jbutton that should run the xml file.

```
public static void runXML() {
    // Create object of TestNG Class
    TestNG runner=new TestNG();

    // Create a list of String 
    List<String> suitefiles=new ArrayList<String>();

    // Add xml file which you have to execute
    suitefiles.add("C:\\Users\\AFSW-NE\\git\\AfsTestBed\\testng.xml");

    // now set xml file for execution
    runner.setTestSuites(suitefiles);

    // finally execute the runner using run method
    runner.run();
```

And that is the method being called when the button is pushed.  When debugging, it seems that the runXML() method is the problem.  It says that runXML() threw NoClassDefFoundError with the cause being ClassNotFoundException "org.testng.TestNG".  So I believe it must be something with the class path, but I am not sure what.  The dependencies in the pom file are there and the jars are there as well.

Answer (score 0):

NoClassDefFoundError happens only if the class is not in the class path.In eclipse, in the buildpath, there is a tab for libraries, in that go and see if the jar is added and if it is, then uncheck the build automatically, and then select it back again. It then works, faced the same problem and someone suggested me to do it and it worked. Try and see if it works, hope it helps..

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work.  I think it is just an eclipse error.  I installed IntelliJ and imported the project and it ran fine.  So some kind of communication error in eclipse.